# iphone development how to get phone logs

Tags: iphone, testing, logging, remote-debugging

Is there a way to get the file with the logs for a tester's phone?

I am developing this app and I want to view what the app outputed in the device logs

However I don't have the posibility to connect it with Itunes through a cable or anything like that

I have some testers that are on different parts of the world

They will be happy to give me their logs but I don't know they can do that?

I know about testflight and it's api for remotelogging..

well I want the apple logs...

Answer (score 0):

You Can use crittercism api. from Crittercism.com